# Will Increasing the system memory, reduce dirty Cache % in Mongo wired tiger

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

I am having a Mongodb replica set with one primary, one secondary and one arbiter.

The hardware specification of both primary and secondary is same, i.e. 8 core, 32 GB RAM and 700 GB SSD.
I have recently moved the database to the WiredTiger db engine from MMap.

According to the documents of Mongo, I know that, page eviction will start when:

- Wired Tiger cache is 80% used.
- When dirty cache % is more than 5%.

My resident memory is 13 GB. I can see our dirty cache % more than 5%, around 7% all the time, also our Wired Tiger cache usage is more than 11 GB, which is around 80% of our WT cache usage.

I can see an increase in CPU usage due to app thread going into cache evictions all the time.

I want to know, if increase the box size to 16 core, 64 GB, is it going to fix the issue?

Comment: App threads shouldn't get involved until cache gets to 95% or dirty gets to 30%.   The background eviction workers should kick in at 80% and 5%.

Comment: i guess, in my case, background eviction workers  are working most of the time, because of that cpu utilisation is high.